# Why does ruby throw an error when i try to convert to int?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make a simple encryption algorithm using ruby.

When i convert to int using .to_i, ruby prints "no implicit conversion of string into Integer(TypeError) from C:/Users/liam/Downloads/encryption.rb:60:in ''".

Line 60 is the following:

```
cleartext.to_i
```

and the rest of the code is:

```
print ">"
cleartext = gets.chomp
print ">"
symetricKey = gets.chomp
puts "cleartext and symetricKey obtained. calculating result..."
STDOUT.flush
symetricKey.gsub! 'a', '1'
symetricKey.gsub! 'b', '2'
symetricKey.gsub! 'c', '3'
symetricKey.gsub! 'd', '4'
symetricKey.gsub! 'e', '5'
symetricKey.gsub! 'f', '6'
symetricKey.gsub! 'g', '7'
symetricKey.gsub! 'h', '8'
symetricKey.gsub! 'i', '9'
symetricKey.gsub! 'j', '10'
symetricKey.gsub! 'k', '11'
symetricKey.gsub! 'l', '12'
symetricKey.gsub! 'm', '13'
symetricKey.gsub! 'n', '14'
symetricKey.gsub! 'o', '15'
symetricKey.gsub! 'p', '16'
symetricKey.gsub! 'q', '17'
symetricKey.gsub! 'r', '18'
symetricKey.gsub! 's', '19'
symetricKey.gsub! 't', '20'
symetricKey.gsub! 'u', '21'
symetricKey.gsub! 'v', '22'
symetricKey.gsub! 'w', '23'
symetricKey.gsub! 'x', '24'
symetricKey.gsub! 'y', '25'
symetricKey.gsub! 'z', '26'
symetricKey.to_i
cleartext.gsub! 'a', '1'
cleartext.gsub! 'b', '2'
cleartext.gsub! 'c', '3'
cleartext.gsub! 'd', '4'
cleartext.gsub! 'e', '5'
cleartext.gsub! 'f', '6'
cleartext.gsub! 'g', '7'
cleartext.gsub! 'h', '8'
cleartext.gsub! 'i', '9'
cleartext.gsub! 'j', '10'
cleartext.gsub! 'k', '11'
cleartext.gsub! 'l', '12'
cleartext.gsub! 'm', '13'
cleartext.gsub! 'n', '14'
cleartext.gsub! 'o', '15'
cleartext.gsub! 'p', '16'
cleartext.gsub! 'q', '17'
cleartext.gsub! 'r', '18'
cleartext.gsub! 's', '19'
cleartext.gsub! 't', '20'
cleartext.gsub! 'u', '21'
cleartext.gsub! 'v', '22'
cleartext.gsub! 'w', '23'
cleartext.gsub! 'x', '24'
cleartext.gsub! 'y', '25'
cleartext.gsub! 'z', '26'
cleartext.to_i
ciphertext = cleartext * (symetricKey * symetricKey * 100)
ciphertext.to_s
ciphertext.gsub! 'z', '26'
ciphertext.gsub! 'y', '25'
ciphertext.gsub! 'x', '24'
ciphertext.gsub! 'w', '23'
ciphertext.gsub! 'v', '22'
ciphertext.gsub! 'u', '21'
ciphertext.gsub! 't', '20'
ciphertext.gsub! 's', '19'
ciphertext.gsub! 'r', '18'
ciphertext.gsub! 'q', '17'
ciphertext.gsub! 'p', '16'
ciphertext.gsub! 'o', '15'
ciphertext.gsub! 'n', '14'
ciphertext.gsub! 'm', '13'
ciphertext.gsub! 'l', '12'
ciphertext.gsub! 'k', '11'
ciphertext.gsub! 'j', '10'
ciphertext.gsub! 'i', '9'
ciphertext.gsub! 'h', '8'
ciphertext.gsub! 'g', '7'
ciphertext.gsub! 'f', '6'
ciphertext.gsub! 'e', '5'
ciphertext.gsub! 'd', '4'
ciphertext.gsub! 'c', '3'
ciphertext.gsub! 'b', '2'
ciphertext.gsub! 'a', '1'
puts (ciphertext)
```

Comment: `ciphertext = cleartext * (symetricKey * symetricKey * 100)` is the actual line throwing the error because it is in only place where implicit conversion would be needed. `cleartext.to_i` would be explicit conversion because `to_i` is explicitly stating convert to integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned your result

`to_i` or `to_s` will return the result which you need to assign back into your variable as shown below.

Assign this way

```
cleartext=cleartext.to_i

ciphertext=ciphertext.to_s

symetricKey=symetricKey.to_i
```

try this

```
print ">"
cleartext = gets.chomp
print ">"
symetricKey = gets.chomp
puts "cleartext and symetricKey obtained. calculating result..."
STDOUT.flush
symetricKey.gsub! 'a', '1'
symetricKey.gsub! 'b', '2'
symetricKey.gsub! 'c', '3'
symetricKey.gsub! 'd', '4'
symetricKey.gsub! 'e', '5'
symetricKey.gsub! 'f', '6'
symetricKey.gsub! 'g', '7'
symetricKey.gsub! 'h', '8'
symetricKey.gsub! 'i', '9'
symetricKey.gsub! 'j', '10'
symetricKey.gsub! 'k', '11'
symetricKey.gsub! 'l', '12'
symetricKey.gsub! 'm', '13'
symetricKey.gsub! 'n', '14'
symetricKey.gsub! 'o', '15'
symetricKey.gsub! 'p', '16'
symetricKey.gsub! 'q', '17'
symetricKey.gsub! 'r', '18'
symetricKey.gsub! 's', '19'
symetricKey.gsub! 't', '20'
symetricKey.gsub! 'u', '21'
symetricKey.gsub! 'v', '22'
symetricKey.gsub! 'w', '23'
symetricKey.gsub! 'x', '24'
symetricKey.gsub! 'y', '25'
symetricKey.gsub! 'z', '26'
symetricKey=symetricKey.to_i
cleartext.gsub! 'a', '1'
cleartext.gsub! 'b', '2'
cleartext.gsub! 'c', '3'
cleartext.gsub! 'd', '4'
cleartext.gsub! 'e', '5'
cleartext.gsub! 'f', '6'
cleartext.gsub! 'g', '7'
cleartext.gsub! 'h', '8'
cleartext.gsub! 'i', '9'
cleartext.gsub! 'j', '10'
cleartext.gsub! 'k', '11'
cleartext.gsub! 'l', '12'
cleartext.gsub! 'm', '13'
cleartext.gsub! 'n', '14'
cleartext.gsub! 'o', '15'
cleartext.gsub! 'p', '16'
cleartext.gsub! 'q', '17'
cleartext.gsub! 'r', '18'
cleartext.gsub! 's', '19'
cleartext.gsub! 't', '20'
cleartext.gsub! 'u', '21'
cleartext.gsub! 'v', '22'
cleartext.gsub! 'w', '23'
cleartext.gsub! 'x', '24'
cleartext.gsub! 'y', '25'
cleartext.gsub! 'z', '26'
cleartext=cleartext.to_i
ciphertext = cleartext * (symetricKey * symetricKey * 100)
ciphertext=ciphertext.to_s
ciphertext.gsub! 'z', '26'
ciphertext.gsub! 'y', '25'
ciphertext.gsub! 'x', '24'
ciphertext.gsub! 'w', '23'
ciphertext.gsub! 'v', '22'
ciphertext.gsub! 'u', '21'
ciphertext.gsub! 't', '20'
ciphertext.gsub! 's', '19'
ciphertext.gsub! 'r', '18'
ciphertext.gsub! 'q', '17'
ciphertext.gsub! 'p', '16'
ciphertext.gsub! 'o', '15'
ciphertext.gsub! 'n', '14'
ciphertext.gsub! 'm', '13'
ciphertext.gsub! 'l', '12'
ciphertext.gsub! 'k', '11'
ciphertext.gsub! 'j', '10'
ciphertext.gsub! 'i', '9'
ciphertext.gsub! 'h', '8'
ciphertext.gsub! 'g', '7'
ciphertext.gsub! 'f', '6'
ciphertext.gsub! 'e', '5'
ciphertext.gsub! 'd', '4'
ciphertext.gsub! 'c', '3'
ciphertext.gsub! 'b', '2'
ciphertext.gsub! 'a', '1'
puts (ciphertext)
```

Update: 
As @engineersmnky mentioned

```
symetricKey = symetricKey.gsub(/[a-z]/) { |letter| letter.ord - 96 }.to_i
```

Comment: additionally you can simplify this drastically using `symetricKey = symetricKey.gsub(/[a-z]/) { |letter| letter.ord - 96 }.to_i`

Comment: @engineersmnky Ah, that's amazing, I will update your suggestions now.