# Ruby ZeroDivisionError

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a encryption alghoritm in ruby. The encryption works fine, but the decryption part fails. The error is at line 67, and says the following:

> decryption.rb:67:ln '/': divided by zero (ZeroDivisionError)

I have no idea why this is happening and i cannot find a answer to my question online.

This is the source code:

```
print ">"

ciphertext = gets.chomp

print ">"

symetricKey = gets.chomp

symetricKey.gsub! 'a', '1'
symetricKey.gsub! 'b', '2'
symetricKey.gsub! 'c', '3'
symetricKey.gsub! 'd', '4'
symetricKey.gsub! 'e', '5'
symetricKey.gsub! 'f', '6'
symetricKey.gsub! 'g', '7'
symetricKey.gsub! 'h', '8'
symetricKey.gsub! 'i', '9'
symetricKey.gsub! 'j', '10'
symetricKey.gsub! 'k', '11'
symetricKey.gsub! 'l', '12'
symetricKey.gsub! 'm', '13'
symetricKey.gsub! 'n', '14'
symetricKey.gsub! 'o', '15'
symetricKey.gsub! 'p', '16'
symetricKey.gsub! 'q', '17'
symetricKey.gsub! 'r', '18'
symetricKey.gsub! 's', '19'
symetricKey.gsub! 't', '20'
symetricKey.gsub! 'u', '21'
symetricKey.gsub! 'v', '22'
symetricKey.gsub! 'w', '23'
symetricKey.gsub! 'x', '24'
symetricKey.gsub! 'y', '25'
symetricKey.gsub! 'z', '26'

symetricKey=symetricKey.to_i

ciphertext.gsub! 'a', '1'
ciphertext.gsub! 'b', '2'
ciphertext.gsub! 'c', '3'
ciphertext.gsub! 'd', '4'
ciphertext.gsub! 'e', '5'
ciphertext.gsub! 'f', '6'
ciphertext.gsub! 'g', '7'
ciphertext.gsub! 'h', '8'
ciphertext.gsub! 'i', '9'
ciphertext.gsub! 'j', '10'
ciphertext.gsub! 'k', '11'
ciphertext.gsub! 'l', '12'
ciphertext.gsub! 'm', '13'
ciphertext.gsub! 'n', '14'
ciphertext.gsub! 'o', '15'
ciphertext.gsub! 'p', '16'
ciphertext.gsub! 'q', '17'
ciphertext.gsub! 'r', '18'
ciphertext.gsub! 's', '19'
ciphertext.gsub! 't', '20'
ciphertext.gsub! 'u', '21'
ciphertext.gsub! 'v', '22'
ciphertext.gsub! 'w', '23'
ciphertext.gsub! 'x', '24'
ciphertext.gsub! 'y', '25'
ciphertext.gsub! 'z', '26'

ciphertext = ciphertext.to_i

cleartext = ciphertext / (symetricKey / symetricKey / 100)

print"\n"

cleartext.to_s

cleartext.gsub! '1' ,'a'
cleartext.gsub! '2' ,'b'
cleartext.gsub! '3' ,'c'
cleartext.gsub! '4' ,'d'
cleartext.gsub! '5' ,'e'
cleartext.gsub! '6' ,'f'
cleartext.gsub! '7' ,'g'
cleartext.gsub! '8' ,'h'
cleartext.gsub! '9' ,'i'
cleartext.gsub! '10' ,'j'
cleartext.gsub! '11' ,'k'
cleartext.gsub! '12' ,'l'
cleartext.gsub! '13' ,'m'
cleartext.gsub! '14' ,'n'
cleartext.gsub! '15' ,'o'
cleartext.gsub! '16' ,'p'
cleartext.gsub! '17' ,'q'
cleartext.gsub! '18' ,'r'
cleartext.gsub! '19' ,'s'
cleartext.gsub! '20' ,'t'
cleartext.gsub! '21' ,'u'
cleartext.gsub! '22' ,'v'
cleartext.gsub! '23' ,'w'
cleartext.gsub! '24' ,'x'
cleartext.gsub! '25' ,'y'
cleartext.gsub! '26' ,'z'

puts cleartext
```

Comment: can you add `print ciphertext`  `print symetricKey `  `print symetricKey `  before `cleartext = ciphertext / (symetricKey / symetricKey / 100)` ?

Comment: In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49979474/477037) you had `cleartext * (symetricKey * symetricKey * 100)`, now you have `ciphertext / (symetricKey / symetricKey / 100)`. What are you trying to do!?

Comment: Ruby strongly encourages method and variable names to be lower-case only, so this should be `symmetric_key`. Case has significant meaning in Ruby, capitals indicate `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` type identifiers.

Comment: Another thing to consider is this code could be boiled down *considerably* by using a hash-style lookup table or some simple math combined with the `ord` function. You're also setting yourself up for failure here as the text `ab` and `l` are not differentiated by your code. Both map to `12`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because the formula `ciphertext / (symetricKey / symetricKey / 100)` makes no sense at all.

1. `symetricKey / symetricKey` is always 1, divided by 100 that's always 0.01
2. `symetricKey / symetricKey / 100` both operands are integers, so 0.01 is rounded down to 0
3. `ciphertext / (symetricKey / symetricKey / 100)` is equivalent to `ciphertext / 0` (see 2.)

Your error is exactly what it says in the message: you're dividing by 0.

EDIT: As a small bonus, your code is broken anyway. `'k'` for example is converted into `11`, but when decrypting that will turn into `'aa'`

Comment: In #1 I suggest you remove `... is always 1, divided by 100 that's always 0.01`, since it's addressed in #2. In #2, "...so 0.01 is rounded down to 0" is an incorrect interpretation of how integer division is done (as I'm sure you know). I suggest you simply remove references to floating point values. Also, I find your first sentence gratuitous and adds nothing. The OP is clearly a newbie. I'll delete this comment once you've seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered, but I'd like to suggest a more Ruby-like way to solve your problem.

If you look at the doc for [Hash#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) you will see that the second form of the method, written `str.gsub(pattern, hash)`, where `pattern` is generally a regular expression and `hash` is, of course, a hash. Here's an example.

```
h = { 'c'=>'C', 'a'=>'A', 'n'=>'N', 'd'=>'D', 'o'=>'$', 'g'=>'G' }

'cat and dog.'.gsub(/./, h)
  #=> "CAANDD$G"
```

`/./` is a regular expression that simply matches any one character in `str`. It first matches `'c'`, then `'a'`, and so on. Consider the first letter, `'c'`. Ruby checks to see if the hash `h` has a key `'c'`. It does, so that character is replaced with the value of `'c'` in the hash, `'C'`. Next, `'a'` is replaced with `'A'`. `h` does not have a key `'t'`, however, so Ruby converts `'t'` to an empty string. Similarly, the characters `' '` (a space) and `'.'` (a period) are not keys in `h`, so those characters are also converted to empty strings.

This form of `gsub` seems perfect for encrypting and decrypting strings.

Let's first construct the encoding hash.

```
arr = ('a'..'z').zip('01'..'26')
  #=> [["a", "01"], ["b", "02"],..., ["z", "26"]]
encode = arr.to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"01", "b"=>"02",..., "z"=>"26"}
encode[' '] = "27"
encode['.'] = "28"
```

So now

```
encode
  #=> {"a"=>"01", "b"=>"02",..., "z"=>"26", " "=>"27", "."=>"." }
```

`'a'..'z'` and `'01'..'2'` are [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html)s. See the docs for [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h). We would normally write those two lines as a single chained expression.

```
encode = ('a'..'z').zip('01'..'26').to_h
```

Notice that the values begin with `"01"`, so that all are strings of the same length (2). If we started the values with `"1"` how could we decode the string `"1226"`? Would that be `'abbd'` (1-2-3-4), `'abz'` (1-2-26), `'lz'` (12-26) or one of the other possibilities. That is not an issue if all the values of the hash `encode` are strings of length 2.

We could construct the hash for decoding in the same way( `{'01'=>'a', '02'=>'b',...}`), but it's easier to use the method [Hash#invert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert):

```
decode = encode.invert
  #=> {"01"=>"a", "02"=>"b",..., "26"=>"z", "27"=>" ", "28"=>"."}
```

If the string to be encrypted is

```
str = "how now, brown cow."
```

we can encode it with

```
encrypted = str.gsub(/./, encode)
  #=> "081523271415232702181523142703152328"
```

which can then be decoded with

```
decoded = encrypted.gsub(/../, decode)
  #=> "how now, brown cow."
```

Notice that the regular expression ("regex") for decoding matches any two characters at a time.

Two points. Firstly, we could use [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) to write

```
encode = ('a'..'z').zip('01'..'26').to_h
encode.update( ' '=>"27", '.'=>"28" )
```

Ruby allows us to write `encode.update({ ' '=>"27", '.'=>"28" })` without the braces (an example of [syntactic sugar](https://medium.com/@Parmaviolet/trick-or-treat-ruby-s-syntactic-sugar-80c9d80a4c4b)).

The better way is to use [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) to write

```
encode = ('a'..'z').zip('01'..'26').to_h
encode.default_proc = proc { |h,k| h[k] = k }
```

This is a bit complicated for a Ruby newbie, but the effect is to cause `encode[k]` to return `k` if `encode` does not have a key `k`. For example, `encode['.'] #=> '.'`.

Comment: Just a tiny problem I noticed: Even if the numbers start with 0, converting them to integers, doing math to them and converting them back, if the number starts with 0 you will lose that anyway. This would turn, for example, `0113` into `113`; the a still turns into a k and the m can't be read because there's only a 3 left, which would lead to an error at best, or a completely incorrect output at worst.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer, if one is encrypting and decrypting strings, what would be the point of converting any of the substrings of the coded message to integers (and doing math on them)?

Comment: Not sure if there's much of a point, but it's what OP does in the original code.